# Trying to reach 100% CPU utilization in IIS and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, cpu-usage

I'm working on an ASP.NET web service application which makes heavy use of CPU.  I've noticed on a 4 core server, the CPU is underutilized.  So I've come up with a simple service to see if it is possible to reach 100% CPU.  Here it is.

The calling client attacks this server with concurrent threads and repeated messages.  Each request takes between 0.5 and 2 seconds to complete (depending on # of threads).  The highest CPU usage it reaches is 80% across all 4 cores.  I get the same result if I use 4 threads or 16 threads, 1 client or 2 clients.  A 2 core box has the same problem.

So, is it possible to reach 100% CPU on a multi-core IIS server with code that isn't in an endless loop?

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable  { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
    {
        switch( context.Request.HttpMethod )
        {
            case "GET":
            {
                string s = "";
                for( int i = 0; i < 999999; ++i )
                {

                    s = s.Substring( s.Length / 2 );
                    s += i.ToString();
                }
                context.Response.Output.WriteLine( "<html><body><h1>Web Service - " + s + "</h1></body></html>" );
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider creating a LoadTest if you have the appropriate SKU of Visual Studio. It would generate a much more 'true to life' test scenario then you throwing a site out there with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generating garbage at full speed. This triggers lots of GCs. Before and after a GC can happen, for a brief duration all threads must be stopped. This is preventing the process from saturating the CPU.

Put in an arithmetic loop. `Thread.SpinWait` does not guarantee CPU usage because internally it asks Windows to deschedule the current thread. It is not a simple "infinite" loop.

Comment: I don't know how to say this, but you've just made a HUGE difference in my code.  I didn't realize that GC had so much impact on multi-threaded applications.  My code was making calls throughout to GC.Collect() trying to reclaim memory from released objects.  Those calls were what was limiting my utilization of CPU. Thank you so much!  It is running 3 times faster on the 4 core now.

Comment: If you wanna say thanks you can switch the green answer flag over ;-)

Comment: I'm switching the answer flag over to this response. With due respect to Mike, this response better answers the underlying question about CPU utilization.  Garbage Collection appears to have a big impact on the performance of Web Services in multi-core implementations.  Websites based on .NET may have a penalty to pay if they do a lot of allocation and releasing of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the thread into a [`SpinWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx) for a very large number of iterations. This isn't an endless loop but it does run for a long time, probably.

```
Thread.SpinWait(Int32.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Well.  That certainly does raise all CPU's to 100%.  Replacing the for() loop above with Thread.SpinWait(99999999) did it.  So IIS can be maxed out, but why would the simple string manipulation not do it?  Is garbage collection some how blocking the threads?

Comment: Why is this important? Are you somehow worried that the process isn't as efficient as it could be? If that's the case, you're better off optimizing your algorithms than worrying about CPU utilization

Comment: Well, its more a case of whether it is possible to fully utilize the CPU with C# code.  In general, assuming no external calls are made, I would have expected a well written application to be able to use all available CPU.  But the above loop, while very simple code, did not.  It suggests that how ever well written my algorithms, I'll never get full use of the CPU's.  It's like an immediate 20% reduction in efficiency.